# Processing muitple kafka topics with single spark streaming context hangs on batchSubmitted

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

```
object SparkMain extends App {
 System.setProperty("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
 val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("kafkaspark").set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs","4")
 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
 val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
 val sqlContext= new SQLContext(sc)
 val host = "localhost:2181"
 val topicList = List("test","fb")
 topicList.foreach{
   topic=> val lines =KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, host, topic, Map(topic -> 1)).map(_._2);
     //configureStream(topic, lines)
     lines.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.map(test(_)).saveToCassandra("test","rawdata",SomeColumns("key")))
 }
  ssc.addStreamingListener(new StreamingListener {
   override def onBatchCompleted(batchCompleted: StreamingListenerBatchCompleted): Unit = {
     System.out.println("Batch completed, Total delay :" + batchCompleted.batchInfo.totalDelay.get.toString + " ms")
   }
    override def onReceiverStarted(receiverStarted: StreamingListenerReceiverStarted): Unit = {
     println("inside onReceiverStarted")
   }
    override def onReceiverError(receiverError: StreamingListenerReceiverError): Unit = {
     println("inside onReceiverError")
   }
    override def onReceiverStopped(receiverStopped: StreamingListenerReceiverStopped): Unit = {
     println("inside onReceiverStopped")
   }
    override def onBatchSubmitted(batchSubmitted: StreamingListenerBatchSubmitted): Unit = {
     println("inside onBatchSubmitted")
   }
    override def onBatchStarted(batchStarted: StreamingListenerBatchStarted): Unit = {
     println("inside onBatchStarted")
   }
 })
  ssc.start()
 println("===========================")
 ssc.awaitTermination()
}
case class test(key: String)
```

If I put any one of the topics at a time, then each topic works. But when topic list has more than one topic, after getting the `DataStream` from `kafka` topic, it keeps printing "inside onBatchSubmitted".

Answer (score 0):

My Bad . I configured it wrong.
setMaster("local[*]") in place of setMaster("local[2]") works.

Answer (score 0):

change **local[2]** to **local[*]** and its working fine.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("kafkaspark").set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs","4")
```